# Error on validating XML at xsi:type value

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlhttprequest, xsd-validation

i have got this XML which i have been using in an HTTP request

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<updateList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="urn:messages_namespace" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace" xmlns:pc="urn:core_namespace">
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="46" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>T Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="44" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>S Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="45" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>K Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
</updateList>
```

and the XSD that i generated for this XML looks something like this,

```
<xs:element name="updateList">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="record">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="companyName" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="internalId" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

But when i trying to validate the same XML against the generated schema, i am getting this error-

```
    This is an invalid xsi:type 'urn:relationships_namespace:Customer'.
```

for all three Customer records in the XML. But the confusing part is, HTTP request is working fine without any changes. Would appreciate any help in this. Been stuck from so long.

P.S.- Have also checked various StackOverFlow answers but none of them worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

XSD is wrong. In a XSD with targetNamespace `urn:core_namespace`, you should define a named type for your record elements, e.g. `Record`:

*Let's call this schema file `core.xsd` for later reference:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- EDIT 2019-03-17: added missing xmlns -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:core_namespace" targetNamespace="urn:core_namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:complexType name="Record">
        <!-- EDIT 2019-03-17: moved 'companyName' element to Customer type in relationships.xsd -->
        <xs:attribute name="internalId" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <!-- EDIT 2019-02-28: ADDED 'record' element-->
  <xs:element name="record" type="Record" />
</xs:schema>
```

In another XSD with targetNamespcae  `urn:relationships_namespace`, you should import the previous XSD and define a `Customer` type as an extension of the Record type:

*Let's call this schema file `relationships.xsd` for later reference:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  targetNamespace="urn:relationships_namespace" 
xmlns:pc="urn:core_namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import namespace="urn:core_namespace" schemaLocation="core.xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="Customer">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="pc:Record">
        <!-- EDIT 2019-03-17: added 'companyName' element (moved from Record type in core.xsd) -->
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="companyName" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**--EDIT 2019-02-28: added schema below--**

And the final schema defining your `updateList` element.

*Let's call this schema file `messages.xsd` for later reference:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  targetNamespace="urn:messages_namespace" 
xmlns:pc="urn:core_namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import namespace="urn:core_namespace" schemaLocation="core.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="updateList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="pc:record" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

*For `schemaLocation`s, this is assuming all XSDs are in the same folder, else change the schemaLocations accordingly.*

**EDIT 2019-03-17**

Besides, please fix your XML to make sure the `updateList` element is in `urn:messages_namespace`: **replace `xmlns:m="urn:messages_namespace"` with `xmlns="urn:messages_namespace"`** (default namespace).

So here is the fixed XML, let's say it's in file `updateList.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<updateList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:messages_namespace" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace" xmlns:pc="urn:core_namespace">
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="46" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>T Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="44" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>S Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="45" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>K Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
</updateList>
```

Here is a piece of Java code for example and clarification on how to validate the XML with the XML schema files (works for me with Java 8 and all XSDs and XML files in the working directory, put that in a class's main method if you want to test it):

```java
// XSD compiler
final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
// Load all XSD files starting with core.xsd
final Source coreXsd = new StreamSource(new File("core.xsd"));
final Source relationshipsXsd = new StreamSource(new File("relationships.xsd"));
final Source messagesXsd = new StreamSource(new File("messages.xsd"));
final Source[] schemaSources = { coreXsd, relationshipsXsd, messagesXsd };
// Compile the final schema for validation
final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSources);
// XML to be validated
final Source xml = new StreamSource(new File("updateList.xml"));
// Validate
final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(xml);
System.out.println(xml.getSystemId() + " is valid.");
```

Comment: Thanks @cyril for the reply. Tried your solution but now i am getting invalid child element error in my XML for pc:record having 'listRel:CompanyName' and says the expected element is pc:companyName but the namespace does not even have this element definition. Could you please help?  And did you mean validating against the second schema you mentioned having tns as "urn:relationships_namespace" ? But that does not have any reference to the element to updateList

Comment: Yes, I meant validating with the second schema (which already imports the first one). And yes, I did not include 'updateList' in my xsd because your XML does not declare a namespace for it, so I didn't know which one it should be. **What is the namespace for 'updateList' element?** `urn:core_namespace`? If I know that, I can update my answer. The XML should start like this: `<updateList xmlns="the_namespace_for_updateList" ...> ...`

Comment: and also i should have specified in my question itself, the XSD i have shown above have the same tns as **urn:messages_namespace**

Comment: OK so your XML is wrong too. Should be either `<m:updateList xmlns:m="urn:messages_namespace" ...> ...`  or  `<updateList xmlns="urn:messages_namespace" ...> ...` (without prefix)

Comment: I have added the schema for "urn:messages_namespace" with updateList, and element 'record' to the "core_namespace" schema because it is used in an element ref.

Comment: sorry for the late reply Cyril, but how should i use the last schema you added? because if i use it after importing the first one, it refers companyName element but not it's namespace which is **urn:relationships_namespace**. And what about the second schema? Thanks in advance

Comment: If your XML library supports XML catalogs, you only need to load the last schema, and a XML catalog with the schema locations for the other namespaces. If the library does not support catalogs, you need to load all 3 schemas (1 per namespace), but load the first one before the other two. As for your issue, in my answer, the companyName is declared in Record type, therefore in `urn:core_namespace`. But if it is only Customer-specific (not for all kinds of Record), then it should be in the Customer type definition and I have to change my answer. Is it for all Records or only Customer?

Comment: it is specifically for Customer type Records (whose companyName we are changing here). Records could be of more types e.g. Sales Order, Accounts etc. i can mail you the actual xml and xsds if that's ok.

Comment: OK, I fixed the XSDs accordingly in my answer. I also added a fixed version of your XML (the updateList element was in undefined namespace) and basic sample Java code to clarify how you can validate your XML with the XML schemas. If you are using other languages, I hope you can easily adapt.

Comment: Hi @Cyril, is there any way i can make this to work in VS? i mean validation of the XML by giving it as the input instance file in the properties of schema file and then validating the instance? without the coding part. I have been trying but not working.

Comment: Do you mean VS as in Visual Studio? I have no idea, sorry.